Stepped diagram problem
The fields located entirely above one of the diagonals have been removed from the nxn array, resulting in a stepped diagram. Each field of the diagram should be filled with one of the numbers 1 or 2. Determine all integers n ≥ 2 for which this can be done in such a way that among the 2n sums of numbers in rows and columns there are no two equal numbers.
The figure shows an example of filling the diagram for n=7 and the considered 2n sums of numbers in rows and columns.

I dont know how to start. With examples?
Please, let me know something.

Hi @machniik. Please accept the existing answer if it addresses your question. If not, please leave comments on what the issue with the answer is.

Nice problem! Such a diagram exists if and only if $n$ is even.
Let $D_n$ denote an $n\times n$ lower-triangular diagram that satisfies the given conditions. I call them good diagrams.
Let us start with some important observations:

The only numbers that can be generated as sums are $1,2,\ldots,2n$.
The number $2n$ can be generated in exactly one way: sum of $n$ $2$'s.
The number $2n-1$ can be generated in exactly one way: sum of $n-1$ $2$'s and one $1$.

I think these observations should provide you with a good starting point. Try to think about what they imply about the structure of a good diagram $D_n$. In particular, think about what rows or columns can generate the numbers $2n$ and $2n-1$. If you want the full answer, continue reading below.

Let us use these observations to construct a good diagram.

Since there are $n$ rows and $n$ columns and we want all the sums to be different, by the first observation, we must generate every single number in the list $1,2,\ldots,2n$.

By the second observation, the only way to generate $2n$ is if either the left-most column or the bottom-most row is all $2$'s. It is easy to see that reflecting a good diagram about the diagonal line through the bottom-left corner gives another good diagram. So, without loss of generality, let us choose the left-most column to be all $2$'s.

Now, if the right-most cell has $2$, then the right-most column sum is $2$, which is same as the top-most row sum. Therefore, the right-most cell must have $1$.

By the third observation, the only way to generate $2n-1$ is if the remaining entries of the bottom-most row are all $2$'s.


At the end of this, the diagram $D_n$ looks like this:

It is easy to see that the sub-diagram formed by the cells containing $\star$'s (i.e., after deleting the left-most column and bottom-most row) is an $(n-2)\times(n-2)$ good diagram. Therefore, every good diagram $D_n$ can be constructed recursively starting from good diagrams for $n=2$ or $n=1$. In fact, this is the only way they can be constructed.
For $n=2$, there are two good diagrams:
  and  .
They are related by the reflection mentioned above. For $n=1$, there are no good diagrams for the trivial reason that there is only one cell, which means the row-sum and the column-sum are the same. Thus, good diagrams exist if and only if $n$ is even.
